# Can't exclude association's fields from select statement in sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, sequelize.js

I have the following code (simplified):

```js
var group = sequelize.define("group", {
    id: {type: DataTypes.INTEGER, autoIncrement: false, primaryKey: true},
    name: type: DataTypes.STRING,
    parentId: DataTypes.INTEGER
}, { classMethods: {
        associate: function (models) {
            group.belongsToMany(models.item, { as:'items', foreignKey: 'group_id', through: models.group_item_tie });
        }}
});

var group_item_tie = sequelize.define("group_item_tie", {}, {freezeTableName: true});

var item = sequelize.define("item", {
    spn: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, autoIncrement: false, primaryKey: true },
}, { classMethods: {
        associate: function (models) {
            item.belongsToMany(models.group, { foreignKey: 'spn', through: models.group_item_tie });
        }}
});
```

When I try to return some records with relationships, let's say like this:

```js
dbcontext.group.findAll({
    where: { id: 6 },
    include: [{
                model: dbcontext.item,
                as: 'items',
                attributes: ['spn']
            }]
    })
```

I also get in result the fields from a tie table `group_item_tie`:

```js
[{
    "id": 6,
    "name": "abc",
    "parentId": 5,
    "createdAt": "2015-05-06T15:54:58.000Z",
    "updatedAt": "2015-05-06T15:54:58.000Z",
    "items": [
        {   "spn": 1,
            "group_item_tie": {
                "createdAt": "2015-05-06 15:54:58.000 +00:00",
                "updatedAt": "2015-05-06 15:54:58.000 +00:00",
                "group_id": 6,
                "spn": 1
            }
        },
        {   "spn": 2,
            "group_item_tie": {
                "createdAt": "2015-05-06 15:54:58.000 +00:00",
                "updatedAt": "2015-05-06 15:54:58.000 +00:00",
                "group_id": 6,
                "spn": 2
            }
        },
```

I see it in generated sql query. How to exclude those from select statement? I've tried a few other things but was not successful.

I hope there is something cleaner then just doing:

```js
delete item.group_item_tie;
```

Answer (score 61, accepted):

I'm going to answer myself as it might be useful to someone in future. So according to [#3664](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/3664), [#2974](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/2974) and [#2975](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/2975) the answer is the following (thanks to **mickhansen**):

```
include: [{
  model: dbcontext.item,
  as: 'items',
  attributes: ['spn'],
  through: {
    attributes: []
  }        
}]
```

And soon it will be documented.

Comment: For the life of me I cannot get this to work... are we sure this works?

Comment: Worked for me @MirroredFate, if you still have it, post your code on pastebin and lets have a look at it.

Comment: @GustavoMeira There is already an issue on it here: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/5590

Comment: I just did empty attributes at the model level and seemed to exclude it in the projection

Comment: It seems it still includes them in the select statement, just removed them in final output...

Comment: Is there any way I can exclude the attributes in 'item' model and only include the through table attributes?

Answer (score 3):

I realize this thread is a bit outdated, but since this is high in the Google search results and I struggled to find the answer myself, I thought I'd add this here.

If you're using `Model.getAssociatedModel()` or `Model.$get()` (for sequelize-typescript), the current answers listed will not work for this use case. In order to hide the model associations you need to add `joinTableAttributes: []`

Example:

```
Model.getAssociatedModel({
  joinTableAttributes: []
})
```

Example:

```
Model.$get('property', <any>{
  joinTableAttributes: []
});
```

At the time of this post, `joinTableAttributes` is not included in the sequelize-typescript types hence the `<any>`

Answer (score 1):

```
through: {
attributes: []
}
```

works for me

Comment: Please elaborate on your answer and how it applies to the original question. The answer should include enough information to present a complete solution.